# How to show elevation like drawer (more depth z axis) for container using box shadow?

Tags: flutter

I want more depth feel for my container. In app drawer right side it has good elevation that clearly show the z axis. How to achieve this with box shadow?

```dart
Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                spreadRadius: 1,
                offset: Offset(4, 4),
                blurRadius: 3,
                color: Colors.black38,
              ),
            ]
          ),
          width: 200,
          height: 80,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Center(
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("child 1"),
                  Text("child 2"),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: You should provide some code for your current container box.

Comment: Please provide a code sample in your question, otherwise we cannot help.

Comment: You can simply use a card.. Of course a drop shadow can be achieved with box shadow.. Put your current container box